# Are there infinitely many pairs $(x, y)$ satisfying $\cos(x+y)=-1$?

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the equation
$$\cos(x+y)=-1.$$

I think $\cos(x+y)=-1$ only when $x+y=(2n+1)\pi$ for $n$ any integer.

If $S$ is the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $\cos(x+y)=-1$, is $S$ infinte?

Comment: I've modified your question for clarity, please do revert any changes that don't reflect your intention.

Comment: How many pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy $x+y=0$? How about $x+y=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any $n$, how what the set of solutions of $x + y = (2 n + 1) \pi$?

Answer (score 0):

You have answered this for yourself already. You are correct in saying that 
$$
x + y = (2n + 1)\pi \implies \cos(x+y) = -1
$$
for all integers $n$.

But then setting e.g. $y_n = (2n + 1)\pi - x$ gives for every integer a pair $(x, y_n)$ such that $\cos(x + y_n) = -1$. This is true regardless of $x$.